How to check if the IP address for the Flask server is valid?
Here is a simple Flask setup.
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World!'

host = '123.123.123.123'
app.run(host=host)

What can I do to check that the host IP address is valid before executing app.run(host), in order to avoid the Can't assign requested address error?

Typically a Flask app is hosted on localhost or can be made externally accessible with host = 0.0.0.0. Is there a reason to have an arbitrary host IP?

You can't arbitrarily choose the IP address on which you run - it has to be the address of an interface on your local machine, or 0.0.0.0 which means the server should run on all interfaces.

The goal is to bind to a particular interface, and the question is to find out whether it would work or not.

To have a specific IP address route to your Flask app, you'd need access to that web server to forward any traffic from said outward facing IP to your app.  You can't just arbitrarily say, "I think my app would look nice at x.x.x.x address, I'll use that." Think of the security implications (and utter chaos) if this were the case.

I did not say that, nor is that the point of the question.

Are you trying to bind to a particular interface? If not, '0.0.0.0' is the way to go. If you are trying to bind to a particular interface you can check that interfaces existence before hand, using things like ifconfig on Linux systems. Or brute force it, by trying to bind to it, and see if it succeeds.
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('123.123.123.123', 8080))

If this succeeds, you know you have an interface with that IP addr.
